# How to use arrays to store values fetch from sql query in php

Tags: php, sql, arrays

What I want to do here is to be able to assign the values from sql query into arrays.
And then compute for the total.

```
<?php

include('conn.php');

$qreports=query_database("SELECT S_PRICE, PID, QTY_PUR, ITEM_ID, CUSID, CNUM, Cust_Name, TDATE  FROM prod_table, customer_credit, sales_trans_items WHERE prod_table.PID=sales_trans_items.ITEM_ID AND sales_trans_items.CNUM=customer_credit.CUSID AND sales_trans_items.TDATE='2011-02-06 09:14:09'","onstor",$link);

$grandtotal=0;

$customer="";
while($qrep=mysql_fetch_assoc($qreports)){


    $pid=$qrep['PID'];

    foreach ($pid as $k => $v) {
    $sids=$v;
    $qtypur=$qrep['QTY_PUR'][$k];
    $sprice=$qrep['S_PRICE'][$k];
    $customer=$qrep['Cust_Name'][$k];
    $tdate=$qrep['TDATE'][$k];


    $stot=$qtypur * $sprice;

    $grandtotal =$grandtotal + $stot;
}

}

echo "Customer: ". $customer."<br/>";
echo "Profit: ". $grandtotal;
```

?>

I tried the query on phpmyadmin before I place it in the code, and it output this:
[image]

Comment: Your question is missing a question. What is wrong? Is your code broken? What output do you get? Which output do you expect/want?

Comment: I have the impression that you believe that $qrep=mysql_fetch_assoc($qreports) will return a 2-dimensional array containing all your results. It does not. It returns a 1-d array containing only one row. The next time you call it, it returns the next row etc. etc. Is that it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood how [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) works: Every call returns **one row** from the result set. `$grep` is an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) with structure `columnname => value`.

That also means that `$qrep['PID']` cannot be an array and your `foreach` loop won't work. In every loop, `$qrep['PID']` contains one of the values you see in the `PID` column in your screen shot.

I suggest you add `print_r($qreq);` in your `while` loop so you get more familiar with the structure of the array.

As each `$qrep` is an array itself, creating a result array is just adding each of these to a new array:

```
$result = array();
while(($qrep=mysql_fetch_assoc($qreports))) {
    $result[] = $qrep;
}
```

Now you are performing some more computation where I am not sure what you want to get in the end but it seems you are multiplying each `QTY_P` with `S_PRICE`:

```
$total = 0;
foreach($result as $report) {
    $total += $report['QTY_P'] * $report['S_PRICE'];
}
```

*(You could however also compute this in your while loop)*

Assuming you want to get the overall sum and the sum for each customer:

```
$total = 0;
$total_per_customer = array();
foreach($result as $report) {
    $customer = $report['Cust_Name'];
    if(!array_key_exists($customer, $total_per_customer)) {
        $total_per_customer[$customer] = 0;
    }
    $price = $report['QTY_P'] * $report['S_PRICE'];
    $total_per_customer[$customer] += $price;
    $total += $price;
}
```

In the end, `$total_per_customer` is an array with customer names as keys and the sum of the  prices as values. `$total` will contain the sum of all prices.

Answer (score 1):

You question is a bit unclear, but i think the answer wont be far a way from the following suggested references:

- As you loop through the rows use
  something like `$array[] =
  $qrep['columnName']` to populate an
  array.
- Then, check out [PHP's array_sum()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php).